# What is the difference between json.decode and jsonDecode in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am making flutter applications, and I am confused which one to use json.decode or jsonDecode to parse and decode JSON from API. Which one to use?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I guess it [is the same](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html)

`jsonDecode` is calling `json.decode`

Answer (score 3):

It's same. If you open json.dart you will see, `jsonDecode` call `json.decode`

```
dynamic jsonDecode(String source,
    {Object? reviver(Object? key, Object? value)?}) =>
json.decode(source, reviver: reviver);
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but since noone mentioned it, here it is:

From [dart:convert](https://api.dart.dev/be/181224/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html) docs:

> Shorthand for *json.decode*. Useful if a local variable shadows the global *json* constant.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by being more specific about what exactly wasn't mentioned by other answers.